# Spring Boot - Streaming Apache FileUpload - Stream ended unexpectedly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inputstream, apache-commons-fileupload

I am trying to use Apache Streaming API with Spring Boot(disabled Spring Multipart resolver). But when I try to convert the InputStream to byte[] I get an exception - **Stream ended unexpectedly.**  Any idea what is wrong?
Code sample:

```
//Server side code - Spring Boot REST Controller
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<MyObjectDto> upload(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
    FileItemIterator itemIterator;
    MyObject myObject=null;
    if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid content passed for upload");
    }
    ServletFileUpload servletFileUpload = new ServletFileUpload();
    itemIterator = servletFileUpload.getItemIterator(request);
    while (itemIterator.hasNext()) {
        FileItemStream fileItem = itemIterator.next();
        InputStream inputStream = fileItem.openStream();
        if (!fileItem.isFormField()) {
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
           //...Pass bytes for further processing
           myObject =doSomething(bytes)
        }
    } 
    return ResponseEntity.ok(Mapper.map(myObject));
}


//Spring  multipart - disabled
spring.http.multipart.enabled=false

// Client code using Apache Streaming API

Request.Post(uri)
              .body(buildMultipartEntityNew(FileUtils.openInputStream(new File("src/test/resources/my.pdf"))))
              .execute()
              .handleResponse(responseHandler);

// Multipart Entity Builder
private static HttpEntity buildMultipartEntity(InputStream inputStream) throws JsonProcessingException {

    return MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                                 .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                                 .addBinaryBody("file", inputStream,
                                                ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM,
                                                "teamfile")
                                .build();
}
```

Exception:

> org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException:
>   **Stream ended unexpectedly** at
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:1005)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:903)
>   at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101) at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2146) at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2102) at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2123) at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2078) at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:721)

Comment: take a look at the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html) you might have to add a max size. With spring multipart I had to add _spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=50MB_
_spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=50MB_ for example, so you probably will have to do something similar there.

Comment: Those configurations are relevant if Spring we're handling multiparts but I disabled spring from doing that and I am directly using HttpServletRequest.

Comment: I understand that's why I said something similar and not the same. It could be that your **ServletFileUpload** also needs a max file size limit. Look at the section **Exercising more control** from the documentation that I send before.

Comment: I played around with those options. Didn't seem to work.

Comment: Besides my file size is 15-20MB not sure if these configs are an issue..

Comment: @AlexP. Looks like my code is working for the file of size 55MB . But I am getting the above exception when file size is 88MB or greater. I tried increasing jetty Post size  server.jetty.max-http-post-size: 1000000000 but no luck. Looks like a size constraint somewhere. I also tried servletFileUpload.setFileSizeMax(-1);
        servletFileUpload.setSizeMax(-1);  ... Not sure what is wrong

Comment: I'm just going to put it out here, because it is not exactly an answer to this specific problem, but if there are those few of you out there desperately looking for an answer to "Stream ended unexpectedly" issues using Spring or Spring Boot, it might be due to your version of Spring using Tomcat v9.0.31 which causes larger requests to be cut off out of nowhere. [This article](https://medium.com/javarevisited/how-we-found-apache-tomcat-couldnt-handle-large-requests-fd41b8b5f8e7) explains it in more detail. TL;DR: Upgrade Spring or Tomcat such that you are NOT using v9.0.31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the problem. Incase someone runs in to similar issue first thing to check is any filters in the chain are trying to wrap/reconstruct the request(containing inputstream). If you know the exact filter you can disable it

```
 @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean registration(PreAuthenticationFilter filter) {
      FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
      registration.setEnabled(false);
      return registration;
}
```

Or you can test by disabling them all

```
    public class DefaultFiltersBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory bf)
        throws BeansException {
        DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory)bf;

        Arrays.stream(beanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(javax.servlet.Filter.class))
              .forEach(
                  name -> {
                      BeanDefinition definition =
                          BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(FilterRegistrationBean.class)
                                               .setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
                                               .addConstructorArgReference(name)
                                               .addConstructorArgValue(new ServletRegistrationBean[] {})
                                               .addPropertyValue("enabled", false)
                                               .getBeanDefinition();

                      beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(name + "FilterRegistrationBean", definition);
                  });
    }
}
```

In my case a custom security filter was unwrapping the request and reconstructing the inputstream and it is only reconstructing the inputstream partially and hence the error - MalformedStream.

I arrived at this by trying these options

1. Disabling all security

```js
security:
  basic:
   enabled: false
management:
  security:
   enabled: false
```

2. Removing Autoconfigured Springs Default Security

```js
spring:
 autoconfigure:
   exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```

Once I knew security is the issue. I disabled security just for POSTs with inputstream and inputstream is coming along unscathed.

```
 @Override public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
       .requestMatchers(ignoreNonJsonMediaTypes())
       .and()
       .ignoring()
       .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST);

    super.configure(web);
}

private MediaTypeRequestMatcher ignoreNonJsonMediaTypes() {
    MediaTypeRequestMatcher
        matcher =
        new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(new HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    matcher.setIgnoredMediaTypes(Collections.singleton(MediaType.ALL));
    return matcher;
}
```